# Filling a specifc part of a multidimensional string array(Out of bounds)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm making a database where you can enter in animals and the supplements that they need. I have to use a multidimensional array. The problem I'm running into is that when a user goes into entering data into the multidimensional array, I get an out of bounds error. I'm confused because I used the same methodology for the user to input the type of animal and the number of supplements needed, but when it gets to actually entering the supplement, I introduced and array hold to keep the supplements for each animal organized. For a more visual reference, my logic wanted to be like this:

Names
Animal Type 1  Supplement 1

The Animal types go down the first column while the supplements fill in a horizontal fashion on each animal. I'll post my code but specifically I've run into issues with the array out of bounds. I suspect it has to do with how I initialized the multi array, but I'm unsure at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

//Nicholas Stafford
    //February 1, 2016
    //This program will allow user input of up to any number of animals and dietary information and then allow the user to display that information when searching the database

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

public class inventory {

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //Initial variables
        int choiceent;
        int numAnimals = 0;
        int numDiet = 0;
        int ArrayHold = 0;
        boolean isNum;
        boolean isNum2;
        boolean quit = false;


        //Scanners needed for input
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in); 
        Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Initial value needed to enter animals into database
        System.out.println("Enter the number of animals you wish to enter:");
        do
        {
            if(input1.hasNextInt()) {
                numAnimals = input1.nextInt();
                isNum = true;

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer value!");
                isNum = false;
                input1.next();
            }

        }
        while(!(isNum));
        System.out.println("You are entering " +numAnimals+ " animals.");

        //Multidimensional array
        String [][] ZooBase = new String [100][100];

        //Array for data types
        int numDietA[] = new int [numAnimals];

        do{ 

        System.out.println("1. Enter the names of each animal");
        System.out.println("2. Enter the dietary information");
        System.out.println("3. Search the array for information");
        System.out.println("4. Close the program");

        choiceent = choice.nextInt();

        switch(choiceent)
        {
        case 1:
            //Data validation for name

            for(int i = 0; i < numAnimals; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the type of animal for animal " +i+ "");
                while(!input2.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter a type of animal!");
                    ZooBase[i+1][0] = input2.nextLine();
                }
                ZooBase[i+1][0] = input2.nextLine();
            }

            //Display Names
            System.out.println("Names");
            for(int j = 0; j < numAnimals; j++){
                    System.out.println(ZooBase[j+1][0]);
            }
            break;

        case 2:

            for(int j = 0; j < numAnimals; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("How many supplements does the " +ZooBase[j+1][0]+ " need?");
                do
                {
                    if(input3.hasNextInt()) {
                        numDietA[j] = input3.nextInt();
                        isNum2 = true;

                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer value!");
                        isNum2 = false;
                        input3.next();
                    }
                }while(!(isNum2));

                }

                for(int k = 0; k < numAnimals; k++)
                {
                    ArrayHold = k+1;
                    for(int m = 0; m < numDietA[m]; m++ )
                    {
                    System.out.println("Enter item " +m+ " for the " +ZooBase[m+1][0]+ "");

                        while(!input4.hasNext("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter a supplement (No integers)!");
                            ZooBase[ArrayHold][m+2] = input4.nextLine();
                        }
                        ZooBase[ArrayHold][m+2] = input4.nextLine();        
                    }
                }



            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        case 4:
            quit = true;
            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Invalid option!");
            break;



        }
        }while(choiceent != 4);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an array is initialized, its size can't be changed. To make sure this does not happen, use ArrayList<>, which does not have fixed bounds. You can find the syntax + all details here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Hope that helps!

ps. you can also initialize just 1 scanner input and use it throughout

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm forced to use a multidimensional array, no array list but I'll just ask the user if they want to enter another supplement for each iteration. I figured that if I defined the array to 100 and asked the user how many supplements that they wanted, it would just fill the array and not actually change its initialized value.